# PayPal recurring payment verification

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

After one has created a monthly billing agreement with a customer; how do I verify that the customer has paid (and not cancelled the agreement) at the next bill statement?

Would I use `GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails` for this information? Basically, I want to automate cancellations/etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ipn end point a subscr_cancel txn_type is sent when this happens. Then you can update a record in your database to account for this.

Ipn messages when enabled send post requests for all kinds of actions such when a Payment is made or a subscription is cancelled. When you receive a message you need to validate the message, determine what message it is, and then perform an action in your application

Ipn info

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/